# awk command in csv: How do I print more than one entry?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet project where I need to have it pumpout a copy with only specific entries in a column. Here's what I have to find one entry in column 3.

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '($3=6411){print}' testdata.csv > testdatacopy.csv
```

but if I wanted to find 6411, along with another entry, such as 6311, how would I do that?

I tried:

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '($3=6411,6311){print}' testdata.csv > testdatacopy.csv
```

but that did not work.

Comment: NB. When I try your example, it doesn't work - `$3=6411` it needs a double equals, otherwise it prints all the rows and an extra one, with 6411 overwriting the existing value.

Comment: You've go to read SOME kind of intro to a tool/language before trying to use it. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the [awk boolean operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Boolean-Ops.html), you want something like `($3==6411 || $3==6311)`.
Also please see the first "**NOTE**" in [the book on sed and awk](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch07_08.htm).

> Make sure you notice that the relational operator "==" ("is equal to") is not the same as the assignment operator "=" ("equals").

If you're looking to match a good number of possible values, making the boolean expression cumbersome, you might try one of these approaches:

1. Use a regular expression that matches any of the right values.
   `awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '($3~/^6(3[12357]1|399|411)$/){print}' …`
   matches `6311` `6321` `6331` `6351` `6371` `6399` or `6411`
2. Fill in an associative array with the values as the indexes allowing you to test for membership in the array:
   `awk … 'BEGIN { '\`
   `'split("6311 6321 6331 6351 6371 6399 6411", v, " ");'\`
   `for(i in v){ a[v[i]] = 1;}\`
   `}($3 in a){print}' file_in.csv > file_out.csv`
3. If the values are luckily in a range you need only test for something like:
   `awk … '($3>=6311 && $3<=6411)' …`

Comment: so if I wanted to do that for these multiple entries such as 6311
6321
6331
6351
6361
6371
6399
6411

would it be ($3==6411 && $3==6311 && $3==6371 &&  $3==so-on) ?

Comment: @Michael `$3` won't be both 6411 and 6311 etc. So use `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and) also for a large range of numbers like these, if you had a (reliably valid) rule (given some assumptions on the input) like `$3>=6311 && $3<=6411` that would make it simpler. Otherwise use pattern matching like `$3~/63[123567]1|6399|6411/` OR define an array of valid values and test that the `$3 in a` where `a` is that array.

Answer (score 2):

Default action of a pattern match is to print:

```
awk -F, '$3==6411 || $3==6311' testdata.csv > testdatacopy.csv
```

Comment: No need to set `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do a regex "or" match with:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '($3 ~/6411|6311/){print}' t.csv
```

Edit: Ed Morton makes a good point - this would match "64112" and "86411" and so on, if the IDs go into longer numbers, unless you anchor the regex to lock the start and end of the field as well.

Comment: Anchor it (`^...$`).